# Hydro installs with no "stacks" file?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, stacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just installed the desktop-full version of hydro.  I notice that there is no "stacks" folder in /opt/ros/hydro.  There always used to be, I believe, with a lot of default packages.  Is this correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76666/hydro-installs-with-no-%22stacks%22-file?/) by [Alex Brown](https://answers.ros.org/users/125/alex-brown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2013-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All packages in hydro have transitioned to use [catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin) instead of [rosbuild](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild) and catkin packages use FHS style code layouts.

If you want to find out where files inside packages install to use dpkg -L

```
dpkg -L ros-hydro-roscpp
```

Will show you where files were installed to for roscpp.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1